# Special search form

Tags: php, html, css, search, indexing

I try to make special search form, with my own design,
I want to make text input and btn is connected in one,
I try all possible solution but always is speace between text input and btn,

here is code:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><input class="search-box" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and css:

```
#searchsubmit {
background: #000000;
}
.search-box {
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

where is my error ?

Thanks.

Comment: a border will for sure leave a space and you need to either NOT use a table or set padding to 0

Comment: dont listen them, about your previous question, you can try device-pixel-ratio, google it

Comment: div {border: 1px solid #000}
@media(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),@media(min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),@media(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25){.one {border: .75px solid red}}

Comment: <div class="one">1</div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="two">2</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#searchsubmit { margin-left:-3px }

<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
  <input class="search-box" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

but does not look right in iOS since the button is rounded

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/NnXcm/

Answer (score 0):

depends on the browser. try this in your css to normalize the table (works for many browers like for example IE):

```
 table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```